# Primefaces fileUpload only works firts time

Tags: jsf, primefaces

When I upload a file, I need to update some componentes. It only works first time I do it.

XHTML:

```
<p:fileUpload id="Uploader" fileUploadListener="#{cc.attrs.updateImageAction}"  
                    mode="advanced"
                    update="#{cc.id}:updatableElements #{cc.attrs.ajaxRender} #{cc.attrs.ajaxRenderCropDialog}"
                    auto="true" 
                    multiple="false" 
                    sizeLimit="#{cc.attrs.sizeLimit}"   
                    allowTypes="#{imageManagerServiceBean.imageFileAllowedTypesRegEx}"
                    label="#{messages['generic.images.select']}"
                    uploadLabel="#{messages['generic.images.upload']}"
                    cancelLabel="#{messages['generic.images.cancel']}"
                    invalidSizeMessage="#{cc.attrs.invalidFileSizeMessage}"
                    invalidFileMessage="#{messages['generic.images.invalidtype']}"
                    >
            </p:fileUpload>
```

Any idea?

Comment: What happens at the second time? Post the errors you receive.

Comment: updatableElements are not updated. updatable elements is an image with the uploaded image file

Comment: Does the `fileUploadListener` get called? Are there any browser related errors (check the developer tools). Give us more feedback, we cant help you with no information given. Provide more XHTML code, java code. Is [that](http://code.google.com/p/primefaces/issues/detail?id=6157) your problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved the problem. I don't know why but changing the value of #{cc.attrs.ajaxRenderCropDialog}, the update works.

Before:    :artistImageCropperDialog:imageCropperDialog

After:   :artistImageCropperDialog:imageCropperForm

ImageCropperDialog xhtml code:

```
        <h:panelGroup layout="block" styleClass="links">
            <h:panelGroup id="imageCropperDialog" layout="block" styleClass="hidden">
                <h:form id="imageCropperForm">
                        <h:panelGrid>
                            <p:imageCropper id="cropperImage" value="#{cc.attrs.croppedImage}"
                                image="/upload/#{cc.attrs.imageTmp}"
                                initialCoords="#{cc.attrs.initialCoords}"
                                aspectRatio="1"
                                minSize="#{cc.attrs.minSize}"
                                required="true"
                                requiredMessage="Hay que seleccionar parte de la imagen"
                                />
                        </h:panelGrid>
                    <h:commandButton id="acceptButton" action="#{cc.attrs.acceptCropAction}" styleClass="hidden">
                        <f:ajax execute="@form" render="@form :messages :form:pictureHandler:updatableElements" onevent="onAcceptCropEvent"/>
                    </h:commandButton>

                    <h:commandButton id="cancelButton" action="#{cc.attrs.cancelCropAction}" styleClass="hidden">
                         <f:ajax execute="@this" render="@form :messages"/>
                    </h:commandButton>

                </h:form>
            </h:panelGroup>
        </h:panelGroup>
    </composite:implementation>
```

Declaration of dialog in other xhtml:

```
<ui:define name="dialogs">
        <app:imageCropperDialog id="artistImageCropperDialog"
                        croppedImage="#{festivalArtistEditPageBean.croppedImage}"
                        imageTmp="#{festivalArtistEditPageBean.imageTemp}"
                        acceptCropAction="#{festivalArtistEditPageBean.cropImage()}"
                        cancelCropAction="#{festivalArtistEditPageBean.cancelCropImage()}"
                        minSize="#{festivalArtistEditPageBean.cropMinSize}"
                        initialCoords="#{festivalArtistEditPageBean.cropInitialCoords}"
                        >
        </app:imageCropperDialog>
    </ui:define>
```